# Does ReDoc have a live editor similar to the Swagger Editor?

Tags: api, documentation, swagger, swagger-editor

I've started using ReDoc to publish my documentation but don't have a good way to know what it will look like before pushing it to my web server. I've used http://editor.swagger.io/ in the past and found it pretty useful. Is there anything like that for ReDoc?

Comment: According to our [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidance, "**Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**...Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you use this project: https://github.com/Rebilly/generator-openapi-repo#features

You can use the swagger editor with it.  It doesn't render a preview of ReDoc, but you can have a local dev environment running and watch that browser window reload.  To start a local dev environment, see instructions from here https://github.com/rebilly/Redoc#development

### Running local dev-server

1. Clone repository git clone https://github.com/Rebilly/ReDoc.git
2. Go to the project folder `cd ReDoc`
3. Install dependencies `npm install`
4. (optional) Replace demo/swagger.yaml with your own schema
5. Start the server `npm start`
6. Open http://localhost:9000

Alternatively, Docker can be used by just running docker-compose up.